# How to activate phyless linux Ethernet driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, ethernet

I was trying to activate Linux phyless Ethernet driver. There are no much information on net. I am using ARM based Linux kernel SOC is connected to a 1GBPS RGMII port back to back without having a real PHY. Came to know Linux has fixed phy  support. Some of the files have used fixed_phy_add function. But still not getting clear idea how to activate. Any kind of help or pointer will really help here.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. I have just done this for our board. What really confused me was that you need to add the fixed phy before the fixed mdio bus is activated. So either you need to add it early in your platform init code or hack it into the fixed mdio code like I did (just to get things working, of course). This patch did it for me.

```
diff --git a/drivers/net/phy/fixed.c b/drivers/net/phy/fixed.c
index ba55adf..7013ef0 100644
--- a/drivers/net/phy/fixed.c
+++ b/drivers/net/phy/fixed.c
@@ -203,11 +203,24 @@ err_regs:
 }
 EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(fixed_phy_add);

+static struct fixed_phy_status fixed_phy_status = {
+       .link           = 1,
+       .speed          = 100,
+       .duplex         = 0,
+};
+
 static int __init fixed_mdio_bus_init(void)
 {
        struct fixed_mdio_bus *fmb = &platform_fmb;
        int ret;

+       ret = fixed_phy_add(PHY_POLL, 0, &fixed_phy_status);
+        if (ret < 0)
+        {
+            pr_err("could not add fixed phy.\n");
+            return ret;
+        }
+
        pdev = platform_device_register_simple("Fixed MDIO bus", 0, NULL, 0);
        if (IS_ERR(pdev)) {
                ret = PTR_ERR(pdev);
```

The next step is to use this phy in your driver, it should be enough to use the name fixed-0:00 as the phy name when you look it up (the :00 is the fixed phy id 0 in the
fixed_phy_add above)

```
snprintf(phy_id, sizeof(slave_data->phy_id), PHY_ID_FMT, "fixed-0", 0);
```

Then the phy_connect your driver already has should find the fixed phy and it should work
as long as the fixed configuration matches the other side (a switch in our case):

```
phy_connect(ndev, phy_id, &_adjust_link, phy_if);
```

There should be a method to make all this work with device tree too but no-one has gotten there yet, AFAICS.

Good Luck.

Comment: The fixed_mdio_bus_init is not the best place to add the fixed phy to the system.  This supposed to be board-specific code.  The added lines should really be placed in your board initialization.  Look at /arch/m68k/platform/coldfire/m5272.c for an example.

Comment: I know. But my board uses devicetree and there is no devicetree support for fixed phys. Even if there was it needs to be added early because the phys need to exist before the fixed phy init routine is called, they cannot be added afterwards. The easiest way to do this was to add it explicitly in fixed_mdio_bus_init. Now that I think about it why not just add a configuration parameter for the number of fixed phys wanted instead of putting this stuff in board files?

Comment: Does the driver also need to call netif_start_queue ?